# "Перерыв!" Что это за предложение?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Перерыв!

Это номинативное предложение? Влияет ли интонация на трактовку (если это произносится с повышенной интонацией)? Отличается ли этот случай от просто надписи на двери? Будут ли отличаться трактовки, если рассматривать этот случай как приказ кому-то перестать работать и как ответ посетителю ("мы закрыты")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть разные подходы, но большинство учёных, в том числе и Валгина, такие предложения не включают в состав номинативных, потому что там отсутствует значение бытийности. Чаще всего они содержат характеристику лиц, явлений, понятных из речевой ситуации, и рассматриваются как **двусоставные ситуативно-неполные предложения.**

*Перерыв!* - это предупреждение: в магазине перерыв, он не работает, поэтому следует подождать открытия. Восклицательная интонация используется для привлечения внимания. Но это не показатель -номинативные тоже бывают восклицательными: *Ну и мороз!*

Не поняла, о каких "просто надписях" на двери Вы говорите, все надписи квалифицируются как какие-то предложения. Вот от вывесок отличаются точно. Вывески к предложениям вообще не относят,там даже точки не ставят, но некоторые учёные относят их к особым нечленимым собственно номинативным предложениям - названиям. Так что нужно смотреть, каково мнение Вашего преподавателя, кого он поддерживает - читайте его лекции.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Можно ли тогда считать слова спортивного комментатора "Удар! Гол! Штанга!" номинативными предложениями? Здесь, похоже, можно говорить о бытийности. Как быть с фамилиями игроков (Пас. Месси. Удар.)?

Comment: Нет, я думаю, это тоже им. падеж в роли сказуемого в неполном  двусост. предл. при отсутствующем подлежащем.Такие конструкции являются сообщением о чем-либо, названном в контексте или ясном из ситуации: " Чичиков еще раз взглянул на него искоса, когда проходили они в столовую: Медведь! Совершенный медведь! "Бытийное - это когда заостряется внимание на том,что этот предмет имеется,  существует, больше никакой информации не даётся, а комментатор радуется:"Гол!", и мы чувствуем пропущенные им слова:"И вот наконец забит гол!" или досадует: "Штанга!", а мы слышим: "К сожалению, штанга помешала..."

Answer (score 0):

Номинативное. Надписи на двери (равно как и на заборе) грамматику не интересуют.

Answer (score 0):

Среди номинативных предложений особое место занимают предложения **с событийными существительными,** обозначающие отрезки времени, явления природы, события: Зима. Ночь. Жара. Война.

Их природа противоречива, так как они имеют отношения ко времени, а это глагольное свойство, поэтому номинативные предложения легко преобразуются в двусоставные, например: Зима (сейчас). Была зима. Будет зима.

(1) Если предложение выполняет **интродуктивную функцию**, то относится к номинативным предложениям с фиксированным настоящим временем: **Ночь. Улица. Фонарь. Аптека.** **Всё это находится в поле зрения наблюдателя.**

**Осень (поговорим об осени**). Для Пушкина это было любимое время года. (Предложение номинативное).

(2) Но: **Осень** (стоит сейчас). Холодно, весь день идет дождь. Это уже не номинативное, а двусоставное предложение.

Аналогичная ситуация со словом ***перерыв***. Сравнить:

(1) **Перерыв.** Большая перемена. В такое время в классе всегда удивительно тихо. Это номинативное предложение, настоящее время **фиксировано.** (Автор говорит о перерыве вообще).

(2) **Перерыв (сейчас). Перерыв!**  Значения разные: мы закрыты; обед, перестаем работать; также табличка на двери. Это двусоставное предложение. Настоящее время не фиксируется, а **длится.**

Comment: >> "Осень (стоит сейчас). Холодно, весь день идет дождь. Это уже не номинативное, а двусоставное предложение".

Где "два состава"?! "Стоит сейчас", которое в скобках, что означает? Подразумевается? Кем? Мне бы за такие фантазии уже сделали последнее китайское предупреждение.

Comment: Не волнуйтесь, всё еще впереди. Ваш "ответ" вообще надо удалить - это мнение, состоящее из одной строчки с неостроумными приписками, но только не ответ. Что касается моих фантазий, то они не мои, а взяты из грамматики. Их пишут специалисты, которые в этих вопросах разбираются лучше вас.

Comment: И где же пруфы? Тут же без них не приветствуется? Так где же всё-таки "два состава" в предложении "Осень"?